# Android Studio crashes frequently without error

Tags: android, android-studio

I seem to be having a problem with my Android Studio installation: it crashes frequently at different points, seemingly without reason; sometimes it happens during startup, sometimes when I'm saving, sometimes when I'm just changing some settings in the menus, or even when I'm just typing up some code. It never "officially" crashes (it never gives me a "has stopped working"/"is not responding" message or any other type of dialog); instead it just exits.

My `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` environment variables have been properly set.

I've been able to code, and test several projects. Aside from the exiting randomly "bug", everything seems to compile and execute fine.

```
Version: 1.3
Build:AI-141.2117773 built on July 28 2015
JRE 1.8.0_25-b18 amd64
Windows 7 SP1 - no updates available in Windows Update
```

Please let me know if I need to post anything else, I will gladly oblige!

Comment: Version of windows? Added that info: W7 SP1

Comment: I suggest you to try fresh Installation or, As it happens because of some internal Intellij's libraries problem.

Comment: Check the log files, to be found in C:\Users\{You}\.AndroidStudio{maybe version number}\system\log

Comment: Try running it in a console.  There might be some useful error messages printed to standard output.

Comment: Seeing the same thing on OSX Yosemite fwiw. Just re-installed and it's hung again... but I'll try a bit longer...

Comment: @mm2001 Im having the same problem on El Capitan OSX, did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @Shatazone - sorry, I can't remember. I switched to another project and it's been fine with that. Perhaps I ended up creating a new project and re-importing the files ... but it's been so long. It does seem to be working ok now though.

Comment: @mm2001 thanks for your reply, I have just found the solution to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880984/android-studio-quits-unexpectedly-on-mac/34902585#34902585

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and install again Android Studio and all the Android-SDK, sometimes the IntelliJ platform upgrades some libraries or install new patches in Android Studio which can generate conflicts and make this strange bugs happen.

I had a problem like this when Android Studio was below the 1.0 version, but I suppose that there can be some problems like that in all versions.

It's a bad solution, but it's the most secure one.

Comment: Seems to be working for the time being, will accept after a bit more testing. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hope I'd been helpful :)