# Android Studio Quits unexpectedly on Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, crash, freeze, osx-elcapitan

I am running Android Studio v1.5.1 on OSX El Capitan 10.11.2.
Android studio starts flickering whenever I move and click the mouse from external monitor to the laptops screen, then suddenly quits without giving any error message.

Is anyone else facing this problem?

Crash Report: http://pastebin.com/xda8wAKN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem:

Open the info.plist in a text editor
path is "/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/info.plist"

update the JVMVersion to 1.7*